# Using iif clause in Ms Access for a column with "Yes/No" Data Type

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a column called `DayShift` in a table which is of `Yes/No` data type (Boolean). The result Output I want is: if the value is true, display "Day" else display night.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT iif(DayShift=Yes,"Day","Night") as Shift FROM table1;

SELECT iif(DayShift,"Day","Night") as Shift FROM table1;

SELECT iif(DayShift=True,"Day","Night") as Shift FROM table1;

SELECT iif(DayShift=1,"Day","Night") as Shift FROM table1;
```

But none of the above work. It just gives me a list of blank check boxes in the output datasheet window. I am using Ms Access 2003. Any help appreciated.

**Update:**

After a bit of research that the yes/no data type in Ms Access 2003 cannot handle null values appropriately. Hence, the error. [Check this link for details.](http://allenbrowne.com/noyesno.html)

**Update 2**

Real Query with the joins. Didnt mention it since i though the information provided above would work.

```
SELECT tblovertime.contfirstname                        AS [First Name], 
       tblovertime.contlastname                         AS [Last Name], 
       tblovertime.employeenumber                       AS [Employee Number], 
       tblsignup.thedate                                AS [Sign Up Date], 
       Iif([tblOvertime.DayShift] =- 1, "Day", "Night") AS shift, 
       (SELECT Mid(MIN(Iif(sector = 1, "," & sector, NULL)) & MIN( 
                               Iif(sector = 2, "," & sector, NULL)) & MIN( 
                               Iif(sector = 3, "," & sector, NULL)) & MIN( 
                           Iif(sector = 4, "," & sector, NULL)), 2) AS concat 
        FROM   tblempsectorlist 
        WHERE  tblempsectorlist.empnum = tblsignup.employeenumber 
        GROUP  BY empnum)                               AS sectors, 
       tblovertime.timedatecontact                      AS [Date Contacted], 
       tblovertimestatus.name                           AS status 
FROM   (tblsignup 
        INNER JOIN tblovertime 
          ON ( tblsignup.thedate = tblovertime.otdate ) 
             AND ( tblsignup.employeenumber = tblovertime.employeenumber )) 
       INNER JOIN tblovertimestatus 
         ON Clng(tblovertime.statusid) = tblovertimestatus.statusid 
WHERE  (( ( tblsignup.thedate ) ># 1 / 1 / 2011 # )) 
ORDER  BY tblsignup.thedate;
```

Comment: If your column is called `isDayShift`, why is your query using `DayShift`?

Comment: sorry about that...My column is `dayshift`. Updated the question

Comment: Looks like your calculated field is displayed as a boolean instead of a text. In your query design, open the properties window then click in the Shift column. In the field properties, click on the Lookup tab, and set the Display Control property to Text Box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second one has it right

```
SELECT iif(DayShift,"Day","Night") as Shift FROM table1;
```

I suggest trying the following to see what's actually being evaluated

```
SELECT iif(DayShift,"Day","Night") as Shift, DayShift FROM table1;
```

You could equally do

```
SELECT iif(DayShift = -1,"Day","Night") as Shift FROM table1;
```

Since MS Access is storing true as -1 and false as 0 (it's not as intuitive as true = 1, but it's probably faster to evaluate in twos-compliment)

**-- edit --**
Since you appear to be using a join, which *can* result in Nul's for Yes/No's, use the nz() function.

```
select iff(nz(DayShift, 0), "Day","Night") as Shift FROM table1;
```

When DayShift comes out null, this will return 0 (false/no) as a result instead.

Comment: @CodeSlave The last query worked well. I wonder why it takes -1 as true. Thanks buddy

Comment: @CodeSlave It gave an unknown error and made the database shutdown. This happened once in 3 times. the reason being null values. http://allenbrowne.com/noyesno.html

Comment: Ahh.. you you should have mentioned that you were using a join. Let me fix that for you.

Comment: Nope. It just crashes with an unknown error. I will update my question with the real query. Sorry about not mentioning about the joins. Just wanted to simplify my question

Comment: @cODESlave I really appreciate your help

Comment: @reggie: Yes/No fields are stored internally as Integers, not true Booleans. `False = 0` and `True = Not False`. Apply a bitwise Not to 0 and the result is the same string of bits used to represent -1 in twos-complement.

Comment: Wait a minute. You ran it three times (same query, and the same data) and one of them failed? Are you sure the DB it self is not damaged. Have you tried a compact-and-repair (take a backup first)?

Comment: resolved it... you 3rd solution works. and when it breaks down, i have to toggle to from -1 to 0 and change the condition. and it work again. Thanks man. I guess thats the only way through. Ms Access sucks.

Answer (score 1):

This one might be stupid, but ....

In case you have some Null values in the DayShift field, Access will not be able to evaluate the formula. You could write your test this way:

```
 iif(Nz(DayShift,0)=-1,"Day","Night")
```

Comment: DayShift can only be Null if it's not a Boolean field in the first place. If it's a Boolean field, testing for Null or converting from Null is a complete waste of time (assuming a Jet/ACE data table, of course).

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following query successfully:

```
SELECT IIf([Table1]![isDayShift]=True,"Day","Night") AS Shift
FROM Table1;
```

I built this in Access 2007 (sorry, I didn't have a copy of 2003 lying around).  The only difference I saw was that it gave the full path to the field instead of just the field name.  However, that shouldn't be an issue.  If it is giving you checkboxes, it would seem that it is not seeing this field as a text field but rather as a checkbox field still.

Bottom line is the above query should work.

Comment: `[Table1]![isDayShift]` is very non-standard -- the bang is not used in Jet/ACE SQL except for references to Access objects. Normally, that would be a dot, `[Table1].[isDayShift]`.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton - Well, I used the Access query designer to build this and since it is targeting an Access object, this would be how you do it.

Comment: the query mentioned just restarts the ms access database. gives an unknown error

Comment: @reggie - That isn't good.  It shouldn't do that.  Have you tried a repair/compact?

Comment: I just tried using the `Table!Field` syntax in the Access QBE, and to my surprise, it did work. It's non-portable, though, and I would never use it. Also, the dot operator is what the QBE uses by default (i.e., you have to manually type in the ! operator).

Comment: Thanks @David-W-Fenton. I didn't know about `!`

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to "DayShift" rather then the derived "Shift" in the form.

The 3rd query (`=True`) show when run in isolation should show Day/Night.

Answer (score 0):

The Access database engine (ACE, Jet, whatever) has a clever/stupid feature that allows an expression in the `SELECT` clause to refer to an `AS` clause ("column alias") in the same `SELECT` clause if that `AS` clause is to the left of the expression. This makes it easy to test expressions with test data without using a table at all (assuming [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070483.aspx), I think) e.g. try executing any of the following statements individually: all should work and produce the expected result:

```
SELECT CBOOL(TRUE) AS DayShift, 
       IIF(DayShift = TRUE, 'Day', 'Night') AS Shift;

SELECT CBOOL(FALSE) AS DayShift, 
       IIF(DayShift = TRUE, 'Day', 'Night') AS Shift;

SELECT NULL AS DayShift, 
       IIF(DayShift = TRUE, 'Day', 'Night') AS Shift;

SELECT CBOOL(TRUE) AS DayShift, 
       IIF(DayShift, 'Day', 'Night') AS Shift;

SELECT CBOOL(FALSE) AS DayShift, 
       IIF(DayShift, 'Day', 'Night') AS Shift;

SELECT NULL AS DayShift, 
       IIF(DayShift, 'Day', 'Night') AS Shift;
```

Comment: Since you're suggesting this, why don't you actually figure out whether ANSI 92 mode is required or not?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: I don't have Access-the-front-end installed on my machine. Rather, I use VBA+ADO code to create an mdb on the fly etc. Regardless, I only use ANSI-92 Query Mode. Apart from compatibility with legacy pre-Access2000 code (i.e. does not apply to me), I can't think of a single advantage of using ANSI-89 Query Mode. I was kind of hoping that someone au fait with "traditional" Query Mode would edit my answer accordingly (hint, hint).

Comment: I assume that people who say they are using Access are using Access. You obviously are not, so whatever I recommend or suggest may have nothing to do with your needs. It's up to you to parse when you're defining "Access" idiosyncratically so that it doesn't actually refer to the database development tool at all. Of course, when answering a question on SO, such a clarification would be helpful to those who don't define "Access" in a strange way. I doubt you care about those people, though.